# Is there any way to iterate through Makefile targets in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I want to do something like:

```
for *target* in *Makefile targets*
do
     *do some stuff*
done
```

in my script. Is there any way to do it??

Comment: So what problem are you facing that prevents you from doing exactly that?

Comment: The usual approach is to add a phony target `all` inside the Makefile that iterates through the existing targets by simply mentioning them as requirements. So you can simply execute a `make all`. But I am not aware of an implicit approach, since it is not that clear to define what a "target" actually is...

Comment: @arkascha Yes, i know about `make all`, but i want to exactly iterate through all targets, not just build them all.

Comment: Ok, so then have a try answering the question I implied: how do you define the set of targets defined inside a makefile? :-)

Comment: @arkascha The set of targets is list of string, and for each string I can run `make *something*` and it will work. Bash auto-completion can show all of the targets in Makefile, so I want something like that but in script

Comment: Do you realize that you did not answer my question? That you avoid it? I'd say is because you cannot give a definition of what a target is and what is not. There are millions of targets defined in most Makefiles. So which ones do you pick, or consider a "target"?

Comment: @arkascha I need all of them. Even if the target just compiles some object file, I need it.

Comment: So still no answer :-)

Comment: @arkascha "Target" is already defined in [`make` man](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), so I define it exactly as they do

Comment: @VarunM The problem is that I don't know how to get the list of targets from Makefile in bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can do is run `make -np` and then parse the output to extract all the targets.  Note that, of course, this won't show you any targets which are created by implicit rules.  If you wanted all of them you could try to extract all the targets *and* prerequisites from the output of `make -np`.

Comment: I hoped that there is more easier way))